# Como actualizar datos automáticamente cuando hay un cambio en la base de datos, react

Tags: django, reactjs

Tengo una duda y espero me puedan orientar, soy nuevo en programación y estoy haciendo una practica sencilla con react y django, utilizo react para el frontend y una api con django para el backend. El objetivo de la practica es crear, actualizar y borrar artículos de abarrotes. Desde el frontend creo el articulo y usando axios lo guardo en la api, después traigo los datos de la api con axios y los guardo en el store de la app para mostrar los artículos en una lista, esa parte ya me funciona bien. Lo que no se como hacer es cuando yo tenga 2 usuarios o mas utilizando el programa si uno crea un nuevo articulo y lo guarda en la api, los demás usuarios no lo van a ver hasta que recarguen la página y traigan los datos con axios. Para hacer que cuando se realice cualquier cambio en la api se actualice de forma automática la lista de artículos en los usuarios es necesario utilizar sockets, ajax... o no debería utilizar una api?. Gracias.

Comment: la respuesta es sockets, aunque también puedes tomar opciones como `firebase`, o `pusher`, que en resumidas cuentas son sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Django Rest Framework te proporciona una api normal como cualquier sistema, pero la reactividad no depende de django sino de react. los sockets y ajax son cosas del pasado la razón por la cual usas react es para dejar de usar esas otras tecnologías.

otra alternativa es usar apis como graphql que hay varios proyectos que integran a django con graphql.

Hay muchos proyectos que integran react con django de manera reactiva.